# How do I prevent pictureBox images from trailing while I move it?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, picturebox, doublebuffered

Hello stackoverflow community. I already tried looking for a similar question but I only found questions about flickering, which isn't the same as the problem I am having.

I need help preventing the `PictureBox`es from trailing whenever I move them across a panel. The application I am making is similar to MS Paint. When I click a `PictureBox` I can click and drag it using:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pictureBox1.Left += (e.X - x);
        pictureBox1.Top += (e.Y - y);
    }
}
```

and the other pictureBoxes which I did Not click are painted to the DoubleBuffered panel, using:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PictureBox pb in pboxes)
    {
        if (!pb.Visible)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pb.Location, pb.Size));
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason when I drag a `PictureBox` it's background Image drags across the painted panel.

Weird thing is, this only happens on the Paint event. If I were to make the panel's background Image something, the moving `PictureBox` won't trail. It only happens when I'm painting `Image`s onto the panel.

Here is an example [image]

I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks.

I simplified the code so it'll be easier to understand.(The trailing effect still occurs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int x;
    int y;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Show();
        pictureBox2.Hide();
        pictureBox3.Hide();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pictureBox1.Left += (e.X - x);
            pictureBox1.Top += (e.Y - y);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox2.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, pictureBox2.Size));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox3.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox3.Location, pictureBox3.Size));
    }


}}
```

And it uses this doubleBuffered panel class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class DoubleBufferPanel : Panel
    {


        public DoubleBufferPanel()
        {

            // Set the value of the double-buffering style bits to true.
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;



            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
             ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

            this.UpdateStyles();

        }


    }

}
```

Now my code calls for 3 `PictureBox`, and 1 `DoubleBuffered` panel.

The form is maximized, `Panel1.size = (2000, 1200);` and each `PictureBox` `size = (700, 700)` and set each `PictureBox`es background Image to a random large detailed image. The trailing effect occurs when I move `pictureBox1` and I can reproduce this every time.

Comment: Did you try calling `Refresh()` or `Invalidate()` on the panel?

Comment: Yes I have wasyl. Both in the pictureBox1 mouse down event, and I tried the Paint event which did not work.

Comment: You could try double buffering. Take a look at this codeproject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer

Comment: sorry if I didn't make it clear mrlucorin, but I already had created a doublebuffered panel. Still doesn't prevent the trailing, altho it prevents the flickering.

Comment: Have you tried with images with very small file size which requires less process? or this is the same for any kind of image?

Comment: Sean87 no sadly file size doesn't matter. Whenever I move a large pictureBox across a doublebuffered panel, its moving pictureBox always has it's background Image trail across the panel. I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the base's OnPaint from your OnPaint handler or alternately doing a selective Invalidate/Refresh from the MouseMove?

Comment: thanks for the response codingthewheel. Are you referring to the OnPaint event inside the doublebufferedpanel class? Because it's a custom class named DoubleBufferedPanel.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was years ago, but I was having similar trouble today. I was click-and-dragging a `PictureBox` for magnifying an image section. The issues were solved by getting the right order of operations: size, move, paint. I solved the issue by:

1. Instantiating the `PictureBox` during the form's `Load` event
2. Relocating the `PictureBox` with its `Location` property during the `MouseMove` event
3. Invalidating the `PictureBox` after the relocation
4. Redrawing during the `Paint` event, which was triggered via `Invalidate()`
5. I had a custom shape (`Region`) for my `PictureBox`, which was set during the `VisibleChange` event.*
6. The `PictureBox` was only visible (`Visible == true`) if the left mouse button was pressed, and the image was large enough.*

   * = optional

Here are modified excerpts from my code. I hope that they are sufficiently relevant.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    Main_PictureBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Main_PictureBox_Paint);
    Main_PictureBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(StartZoom);
    Zoom_PictureBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(StartZoom);
    Main_PictureBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MoveZoom);
    Main_PictureBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(EndZoom);
    Main_PictureBox.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(EndZoom);
    Zoom_PictureBox.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(EndZoom);
    Zoom_PictureBox.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(Zoom_PictureBox_VisibleRegion);
    Zoom_PictureBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Zoom_PictureBox_Paint);
}
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int H = flowLayoutPanel1.Height - flowLayoutPanel1.Margin.Size.Height;
    Main_PictureBox.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 0);
    Main_PictureBox.MaximumSize = new Size(flowLayoutPanel1.Width, H);
}
private void Main_PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Main_PictureBox.Parent.MaximumSize = Main_PictureBox.Size + Main_PictureBox.Margin.Size;
}
private void DisplayImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image img = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;

    int W = img.Width;
    int H = img.Height;
    float ratio = (float)W / (float)H;

    Main_PictureBox.Image = img;
    Main_PictureBox.Size = new Size(W, H);
    float TestRatio = ((float)Main_PictureBox.Width / (float)Main_PictureBox.Height);
    if (TestRatio < ratio)
        Main_PictureBox.Height = (int)((float)Main_PictureBox.Width / ratio);
    else if (TestRatio > ratio)
        Main_PictureBox.Width = (int)((float)Main_PictureBox.Height * ratio);
}
private void Zoom_PictureBox_VisibleRegion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
    {
        gp.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Zoom_PictureBox.Width, this.Zoom_PictureBox.Height));
        this.Zoom_PictureBox.Region = new Region(gp);
    }
}
private void Zoom_PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Main_PictureBox.Image, e.ClipRectangle, cropRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
private void StartZoom(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && scale > 1.25)
    {
        int dX = Zoom_PictureBox.Width / 2;
        int dY = Zoom_PictureBox.Height / 2;
        Zoom_PictureBox.Visible = true;
        Zoom_PictureBox.Location = new Point(e.X - dX, e.Y - dY);
    }
}
private void MoveZoom(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Main_PictureBox.Image != null)
    {
        Zoom_PictureBox.Visible = (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && scale > 1.25);
        if (Zoom_PictureBox.Visible && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            int dX = Zoom_PictureBox.Width / 2;
            int dY = Zoom_PictureBox.Height / 2;

            Zoom_PictureBox.Location = new Point(e.X - dX, e.Y - dY);
            Zoom_PictureBox.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
private void EndZoom(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        EndZoom();
}
private void EndZoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EndZoom();
}
private void EndZoom()
{
    Zoom_PictureBox.Visible = false;
}
private Rectangle cropRectangle
{
    get
    {
        if (Main_PictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            Point origin = Main_PictureBox.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
            float X = (float)(MousePosition.X - origin.X);
            return new Rectangle(
                (int)(scale * X) - Zoom_PictureBox.Width / 2,
                (int)(scale * (float)(MousePosition.Y - origin.Y)) - Zoom_PictureBox.Height / 2,
                Zoom_PictureBox.Width,
                Zoom_PictureBox.Height);
        }
        else
            return new Rectangle();
    }
}
private float scale
{
    get
    {
        if (Main_PictureBox.Image != null)
            return (float)Main_PictureBox.Image.Height / (float)Main_PictureBox.Height;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```